# Why Demazure operator is an endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[P]$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $P$ be the weight lattice of some Lie algebra. Let 
$$
\Delta_{\alpha}(u) = \frac{u-s_{\alpha}\cdot u}{1-e^{-\alpha}},
$$
where $\alpha$ is a root, $u \in P$. In [the article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demazure_module), it is said that Demazure operator is an endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[P]$. For $u \in \mathbb{P}$, why $\frac{u-s_{\alpha}\cdot u}{1-e^{-\alpha}}$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[P]$? It is easy to see that $u-s_{\alpha}\cdot u$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[P]$. But I don't know how to show that $\frac{u-s_{\alpha}\cdot u}{1-e^{-\alpha}}$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[P]$. Thank you very much.

Comment: What does $e^{-\alpha}$ mean when $\alpha$ is a root?

Comment: @Tobias, I guess (I'm sure you do, too!) that $e^{-\alpha}$ is the basis element corresponding to $-\alpha\in P$ in the group ring $\Bbb{Z}[P]$, but can't hurt to make sure.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen actually, that didn't even occur to me for some reason.

Comment: Hint: If $u=e^{k\alpha}$ so that $s_\alpha(u)=e^{-k\alpha}$, then
$$\Delta_\alpha(u)=\frac{e^{k\alpha}-e^{-k\alpha}}{1-e^{-\alpha}}=
e^{k\alpha}\frac{1-e^{-2k\alpha}}{1-e^{-\alpha}},$$ where you can convert the latter factor to an element of $\Bbb{Z}[P]$ with the aid of the formula for a geometric sum : $(1-q^{2k})/(1-q)=1+q+q^2+\ldots+q^{2k-1}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you very much. Why elements in $\mathbb{Z}[P]$ is of the form $e^{k \alpha}$? I know that $s_{\alpha_i}$ ($\alpha_i$ is a simple root) is a simple reflection. How do we define $s_{\alpha}$ when $\alpha$ is not a simple root? Why $s_{\alpha} \cdot u = s_{\alpha}(u + \rho) - \rho = e^{-k\alpha}$?

Comment: Well, I forgot about the dot action. But I never claimed that $u$ would be of the form $e^{k\alpha}$. That's why I called it a hint. If $\lambda\in P$, then $s_\alpha(e^\lambda)=e^{\lambda-n\alpha}$ for some integer $n$. You take it from there!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you very much. Usually, weights are linear combinations of roots. Why $e^{\alpha}$ is also a weight? Here $\alpha$ is a root.

Comment: IMHO for that fraction to make sense we need to interpret elements of $P$ as basis elements of $\Bbb{Z}[P]$, so instead of $\lambda$ we write $e^\lambda$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, now I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: Think of $\Bbb{Z}[P]$ as the ring that contains all the formal characters. For example the $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-module that has 1-dimensional weight spaces with weights $2\alpha,\alpha,0,-\alpha,-2\alpha$ has as its character $$\chi=e^{2\alpha}+e^\alpha+e^0+e^{-\alpha}+e^{-2\alpha}\in\Bbb{Z}[P].$$

Comment: Good! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement the excellent suggestions for computing an explicit formula made by @JyrkiLahtonen in the comments, here is a somewhat different strategy: show that the element $1-e^{-\alpha}$ generates the ideal of functions in $\mathbf{Z}[P]$ vanishing on the fixed space of $s_\alpha$ (acting on the Cartan), and then observe that $u-s_\alpha u$ is zero on the fixed space of $s_\alpha$.

This is the strategy one must use in somewhat more general contexts where the combinatorics of root systems is not available. But in any case, for computing with Demazure operators the explicit formulas are extremely important. I suggest you understand both approaches!